# Передача массива по значению С++

Tags: c++, массивы

Говорят что в С++ нельзя передать массив по значению в функцию, тогда объясните что делает мой кусок кода: `

```
void f3(int A)
{
    (&A)[3] = 45;
    cout << (&A)[3] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    int A[5];
    f3(*A);
    cout << A[3]<<endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код передает в функцию значение нулевого элемента массива А. Далее, как тут уже сказали, у Вас будет неопределенное поведение и скорее всего затрется память.

> Говорят что в С++ нельзя передать массив по значению в функцию

Передать массив по значению в С++ вполне можно (но, как правило, не нужно). Например так:

```
struct a{
int b[10];
};

void f3(a A){
A.b[3] = 45;
cout << A.b[3] << endl;
}
```

В этом случае в стеке создается копия структуры типа "a" и массива "b" в ней. В этой копии модифицируется третий элемент массива "b". После выхода из функции копия структуры, созданной в стеке (и соответственно копия массива в которой модифицировался третий элемент) теряется.

UPD1:

UPD1 удалено как ошибочное. Желающие могут посмотреть в правках.

UPD2:

Действительно, как подсказывает коллега HolyBlackCat, все равно передается только указатель на массив. Значит без структуры или класса не получится передать массив в функцию по значению. Это потому, что у массива нет конструктора копирования по умолчанию, а трансляторы теперь умные стали. А у структуры или класса есть конструктор копирования по умолчанию (побайтовое копирование).

Comment: @Arhad Естественно, можно обойтись и без структуры. Но это уж я написал для большей наглядности. Ну вот, а Arhad уже стер свой комментарий.

Comment: можно обойтись без структуры?

Comment: @digital-mag См. UPD1 в ответе.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 С `typedef` вы все равно передаете в функцию указатель. Проверьте, напечатайте `sizeof(ia)` в функции.

Comment: @digital-mag См. UPD2 в ответе.

Answer (score 5):

Выражение `(&A)[3] = 45;` берет адрес локальной переменной и записывает по нему значение 45 со смещением 3, что является Неопределенным Поведением. Соответственно что реально произойдет - неизвестно. Зато однозначно известно, что тут нет никакой передачи массива.